# Value Comparison using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to check if the two number string is the same using regex pattern in Java.
Can someone please let me know what I am doing wrong here or better way to write the regex pattern.

`java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^(?!12345\$)").matcher("123454").matches()` should return true

`java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^(?!12345\$)").matcher("12345").matches()` should return false

[Regex Validator](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: Please detail, do you want to find i a string includes another but not without suffix ?

Comment: Your example does not correspond to your explanation. You state that "two number string is the same" but then in your second example they *are* the same and you state that it should return false. Which is it?

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `$` as well? Or did you mean to do `^(?!12345)$`?

Comment: Why negative lookahead? Why not simply `!compile("^12345$").matcher(input).matches()`? (i.e. _not_ matches the input)

Comment: But also keep in mind: Why not a simple equality comparison? `!"12345".equals("12345")`

Comment: Your requirement is not clear at all. Either you edit your question to clarify what exactly you want to do or I'm afraid the question will be closed. Your question should have details like what is input string and what is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Using negative lookaheads seems like overkill here (and they can be quite tricky to get right, because they do not consume any characters from the input).

It is easier to invert the result in your host language, not directly in the regex. (sounds like: I have a problem, so I'll use regex. Now I have two problems).

Suggestion:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^12345$");
!pattern.matcher("123454").matches(); // == true
!pattern.matcher("12345").matches(); // == false
```